# $n$ vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ with dot product $-1$. Does this force that they are in $\{-1,+1\}^{n-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was thinking about a problem and this question came to my mind:

Let $\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ be $n$ vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that for all $1\leq i,j\leq n, i\neq j$ we have $v_i \cdot v_j=-1$. Also let $v_i=({w_1}_i,\cdots, {w_{(n-1)}}_i)$. Does this force that $ {w_j}_i\in \{-1,+1\}$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$ ?

If this is true, that problem would easily be solved. However, I wasn't able to prove this statement or give a counter example.

Comment: More generally, you can apply an inner product preserving transformation, such as a rotation, to all the vectors. And make any kind of components appear (within a range bounded from above by the length of the vectors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not. Take the vertices of an equilateral triangle centered at the origin in $\Bbb R^2$. The vectors will form angles of $2\pi/3$; if you make their lengths $\sqrt2$, the dot products will be $-1$. Specifically, take
$$v_1 = \sqrt2\big(1,0\big), \quad v_2 = \sqrt2\big({-}\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}2\big),\quad v_3 = \sqrt2\big({-}\frac12,{-}\frac{\sqrt3}2\big).$$

Comment: I think for $\mathbb{R}^3$ we can take a tetrahedron and find four vectors with such properties. Now can we do this for any $n$? for example, is there such a shape for $n=5$? like something that has 5 vertices in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and "equilateral triangle" as faces (I would assume 8 faces) so that we can find 5 vectors with the said properties in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: You might look up [polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_polytopes_and_compounds#5_dimensions) in $n$ dimensions.